# How can we find $\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty}\int_{1}^{n} \frac{\cos(nx)(x-1)}{\sqrt{\ln^3(x)(1+x^4)}}dx $?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

I have a question about improper integrals:

How can we find $\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \int_{1}^{n} \frac{\cos(nx)(x-1)}{\sqrt{\ln^3(x)(1+x^4)}}dx$?

$\textbf{Some effort:}$

We know that $-1 \leq \cos(nx) \leq 1$, so we will try to sandwich it:

$$-\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \int_{1}^{n} \frac{(x-1)}{\sqrt{\ln^3(x)(1+x^4)}}dx \leq \lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \int_{1}^{n} \frac{\cos(nx)(x-1)}{\sqrt{\ln^3(x)(1+x^4)}}dx \leq \mbox{$\displaystyle\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \int_{1}^{n} \frac{(x-1)}{\sqrt{\ln^3(x)(1+x^4)}}dx$} $$
The next step is to get rid of the natural logarithm, which will be by using the change of variables and letting $\ln(x)=u$. But this makes the situation worse. I am interested of using again sandwich rule for natural logarithm as well. But I do not know that $\ln(x) < ?$ and $\ln(x) > ?$ for $x \in [0,+\infty]$?

Can you please give me an idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Three questions: 1) What is $n$? 2) Your expression $\ln^3(x)$ will make the expression inside the square root negative for $0<x<1$. How should that be interpreted? 3) The tag `funcitonal-analysis` is probably wrong here. Can you please remove it?

Comment: @mickep Thanks! Sorry I forgot to write $n \rightarrow + \infty$. But I think as I used Sandwich and dropped $cos(nx)$, so no longer I needed $n \rightarrow + \infty$? I removed Functional Analysis.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. But if you remove $n$, then you cannot use it. This means that your bounds are "useless", since it only bounds your integral between two positive numbers. Also, what about my second question?

Comment: @mickep Thanks! About the second question, I have no idea! Because this is the statement of the question and so there is two possibility, 1) The statement is wrong or 2) The statement is right? Against the fact that you say is wrong? Which I also think is correct. So then if we change the bounds to $[1,+\infty]$ then we also will remove the absolute value as well. But still I am not sure that the bound of the integration is wrong?

Comment: I would ask the person giving the assignment to clarify this issue.

Comment: @mickep Is not an assignment. It is from a series of questions in Functional Analysis, which I am working on them.

Comment: And the source of those assignments is who? If it is a teacher, you know what to do, if it is a book, consider reporting to the author. I mean, the integral could be made to make sense as is, but I doubt that the meaning is to have a complex-valued integral.

Comment: @mickep I will change the question

Comment: @mickep I think now it is better?

Answer (score 3):

Note that the integral
$$\int_1^{+\infty}  {\frac{{x - 1}}{{\sqrt {(1 + {x^4}){{\ln }^3}x} }}dx} $$ converges absolutely, the only problematic point is $1,+\infty$. At $x=+\infty$, it converges because $$\int_{}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{x\ln^{3/2} x} dx$$ converges. You can easily show that it is convergent at $x=1$ too.

---

From now on, I will denote $(x-1)/\sqrt{(1+x^4)\ln^3 x}$ by $f(x)$. Then
$$\lim_{n \to +\infty} \int_{1}^{n} f(x)\cos(nx) dx = \lim_{n \to +\infty} \int_{1}^{+\infty} f(x)\cos(nx) dx - \lim_{n \to +\infty} \int_{n}^{+\infty} f(x)\cos(nx) dx$$
The first limit tends to $0$ by Riemann-Lebesgue lemma since $f$ is absolute convergent, for the second, simply note that
$$\left| \int_{n}^{+\infty} f(x)\cos(nx) dx \right| \leq \int_{n}^{+\infty} |f(x)| dx \to 0$$
so the overall limit is $0$.

Comment: Many thanks! Sorry I have some questions. Why it is convergent at $x=1$? And what is the difference between $\infty$ and $+\infty$, where that you limit $n \to +\infty$

Comment: @Nikita   Try replacing $\ln x$ by $x-1$, this does not alter the convergence at $x=1$. $\infty$ and $+\infty$ are the same in my answer.

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot understand it. By which criteria we can replace $\ln x$ by $x-1$? And even after replacing, we have $\int_{1}^{n} \frac{\cos(nx)}{\sqrt{(x-1)(1+x^4)}}$, which after limiting $n \to \infty$ and by taking absolutr convergence in account, we have $\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{(x-1)(1+x^4)}}$, and then can you please explain it more? Thanks!